# Activity Selection with Limited Money using Dynamic Programming

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I'm learning Dynamic Programming, I solved several DP problems, but I found this one is quite difficult for my level. For me this problem is much difficult than the simple activity selection.

So, given N activity with Cost in each activity, choose maximum activity, you can't spend more than M amount of money.

1<=N,M<=10^5
1<=start <= end <=10^5
1<=Cost <= 10^5 

So for example we have 5 Activities and 11 Money
Format:
**From-To -> Cost**
1-3 -> 5
1-5 -> 9
4-6 -> 6
5-6 -> 1
6-10 -> 1
1-5, 5-6, 6-10 = 9 + 1 +1 = 11
Thus, the answer is 3 activity
Of course, if there’s another answer with same maximum amount of activity: 1-3, 5-6, 6-10, so you can choose any answer you want.
And here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct temp{
    int from;
    int to;
    int cost;
};
using data = vector<temp>;

int f(data a, int len, int m){
    if (len<0 || m<0) return 0;
    int val=0;
    for (int i=0; i<len; i++){
        if (a[len].from >= a[i].to)
            val=max(val,f(a,len-i-1,m-a[len].cost)+1);
        else
            val=max(val,f(a,len-i-1,m)+1);//try another activity
    }
    return val;
}


int main(){
    data activity;
    int n,m;
    cin >>n >> m;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        int a,b,c;
        cin >> a >> b >> c;
        activity.push_back({a,b,c});
    }
    cout << f(activity,activity.size()-1,m);
}
```

What's wrong with my code? I know there are several things are wrong, but i don't know where. How to fix bug in my recursion?
Also, if possible, can you make the algorithm faster? Without changing to bottom up method

Comment: Please take some time to read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: Ok i just fixed that.

Comment: Please specify the constraints for the problem. What is the size of the graph, number of edges, amount of money etc...

Comment: Are you looking for only dp solution ? also as mentioned by Pham above, can you please provide constraints for the above problem ?

Comment: Okay i just provide the constraints.

Comment: One more question: What should be maximized ?
If number of the activities that can be performed by a single person should be maximized, in your example, 1-3, 5-6, 6-10 = 5 + 1 + 1 = 7 < 11 is also an answer.
OTOH, If total cost should be maximized, 1-3, 4-6 = 5 + 6 = 11 is also an answer. I already solved this problem in both cases.

Comment: Yes we should maximized the total number of activities can be done with given limited amount of money.

Answer (score 1):

I feel that this is a mixed problem of the weighted activity problem and the knapsack problem.
It is difficult, but very interesting and a great learning opportunity.
I propose a DP. method in the following post.
If I mistake something, please someone correct me.
Then I hope to have a constructive discussion.

---

### Approach

First, we label activities as `A = {a1, a2, .., aN}` and sort them by finishing time like as follows:

```
  |----|a1
     |-----|a2
       |-------|a3 
           |-----|a4
                 ....
```

Next,

- Let `S(A,M)` be optimal solutions to activities `A` with amount `M`.
- Let `L(a)` be all activities of `A` strictly in the left of an element `a`
  of `A`.

  ```
  example.)
              |----|a1
                 |-----|a2          L(a4)={a1, a2}
                   |-------|a3 
                       |-----|a4
                             ....
  ```

We could search `S(A,M)` starting from the leftmost activity `a1` and proceeding to the rightmost activity `aN`.
For each activity `ai`, we can consider its left region `L(ai)`.

**If `M` is infinite**, in `i`-th step, the union of `S(L(ai),M)` and `ai` is a candidate for optimal solution. Thus the subproblem is `S(L(ai),M)`. 
In this step we already have `S(a1,M)`,`S({a1,a2},M)`,..., `S({a1,...,a_i-1},M)`.
Since `a1,...,aN`  are sorted by their finishing time, we can get `S(L(ai),M)` as one of them or some of them.
This recursive approach is the starting point for the current problem.

```
  example.) M=infinity

  |----|(a1,cost=2)          subproblem of 1st step: S(L(a1),M)=empty
       |---|(a2,1)           subproblem of 2nd step: S(L(a2),M)={a1}
           |----|(a3,2)      subproblem of 3rd step: S(L(a3),M)={a1,a2}
           |--------|(a4,4)  subproblem of 4th step: S(L(a4),M)={a1,a2}=S(L(a3),M)
                   ....                                         ^^^^^^^^^^ cached!
```

**If `M` is finite**, the union of `S(L(ai),M-cost(ai))` and `ai` is a candidate for optimal solution. Thus we must solve not `S(L(ai),M)` but `S(L(ai),M-cost(ai))`.
In this case, a subproblem in each step is not necessarily cached.

```
  example.) M=5

  |----|(a1,2)               subproblem of 1st step: S(L(a1),3)=empty
       |---|(a2,1)           subproblem of 2nd step: S(L(a2),4)={a1}
           |----|(a3,2)      subproblem of 3rd step: S(L(a3),3)={a1,a2}
           |--------|(a4,4)  subproblem of 4th step: S(L(a4),1)={a2}!=S(L(a3),3)
                   ....                                         ^^^^^^^^ uncached!
```

Therefore in case of the standard weighted activity selection problem with infinite `M`, we can always focus on the most active combinations of activities.
But in the current problem with finite `M`, we have to cache various combinations which have costs less than `M` in recursive steps.

---

### Implementation

**Memorization**

Appropriate cache table structure is different depending on whether `M` if infinite or not. 
If `M` is infinite, 1 dimensional cache table is enough to execute dynamic programming.
But if `M` is finite, we need 2 dimensional cache table. In your example, it becomes as follows:

```
                                         end
            3     4     5        6                   10 <= end
       1 |     |     |     |   [5,6]   |            [5,6],[6,10]             |
       2 |     |     |     |   [5,6]   |            [5,6]+[6,10]             |
money  3 |     |     |     |   [5,6]   |            [5,6]+[6,10]             |
       4 |     |     |     |   [5,6]   |            [5,6]+[6,10]             |
       5 |[1,3]|[1,3]|[1,3]|[1,3],[5,6]|            [5,6]+[6,10]             |
       6 |[1,3]|[1,3]|[1,3]|[1,3]+[5,6]|[1,3]+[5,6],[1,3]+[6,10],[5,6]+[6,10]|
      ...  ...
```

Thus I define the following cache table class `CacheTable`:

- A cache table `std::map<std::pair<to,money>,Activities>> table_` caches elements of `S({a|a of A, a<=to},money)`.
- `CacheTable::operator()` is used to access the cache table.
- `CacheTable::getCachedOptimal` is used to find an optimal solution from cached results within constraints of finishing time and money.

My quick implementation is as follows:

```
struct activity
{
    std::size_t from;
    std::size_t to;
    std::size_t cost;
};

using Activities = std::vector<activity>;

class CacheTable
{
    // (to,money) --> cached optimal activities
    std::map<std::pair<std::size_t,std::size_t>, Activities> table_;

public:
    Activities& operator()(std::size_t to, std::size_t money)
    {
        auto key = std::make_pair(to, money);
        auto it = table_.find(key);

        if(it == table_.cend()){
            it = table_.emplace_hint(it, std::move(key), Activities());
        }

        return it->second;
    }

    Activities getCachedOptimal(std::size_t to, std::size_t money) const
    {
        Activities cachedOptimal;

        for(auto it = table_.begin(); it != table_.cend(); ++it)
        {
            if((it->first.first <= to) && (it->first.second <= money))
            {
                if(it->second.size() > cachedOptimal.size()){
                    cachedOptimal = it->second;
                }
            }
        }

        return cachedOptimal;
    }
};
```

**Solver**

Using the above cache table, we can implement a DP. solver of the current problem as follows.
This solver can find only single element of `S(A,M)`.
[**DEMO is here**.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5ZcVXk1dEmu65zHP)
While this should works, I think there are more efficient ways to solve this problem.

```
class DPSolver
{
    Activities activities_;
    mutable CacheTable cacheTable_;

    Activities impl(std::size_t from, std::size_t to, std::size_t money) const
    {
        if((from >= to) || (money == 0)){
            return {};
        }

        const auto cache = cacheTable_(to, money);
        if(!cache.empty()){
            return cache;
        }

        for(const auto& act_i : activities_)
        {            
            if((act_i.to <= to) && (money >= act_i.cost))
            {
                const auto remaining = (money - act_i.cost);

                auto acts = impl(from, act_i.from, remaining);
                const auto thisCost = calcCost(acts) + act_i.cost;

                const auto found = cacheTable_.getCachedOptimal(act_i.to, thisCost);

                if(found.size() < (acts.size()+1))
                {
                    acts.push_back(std::move(act_i));
                    cacheTable_(act_i.to, thisCost) = acts;
                }
            }
        }

        return cacheTable_.getCachedOptimal(to, money);
    }

public:
    DPSolver(const Activities& activities) : activities_(preprocess(activities))
    {}

    static Activities preprocess(const Activities& activities)
    {
        auto sorted(activities);

        // preprocessing to order by finished time "to".
        std::sort(
            sorted.begin(), sorted.end(),
            [](const activity& al, const activity& ar)
            { return std::tie(al.to, al.from, al.cost) < std::tie(ar.to, ar.from, ar.cost); });

        return sorted;
    }

    static std::size_t calcCost(const Activities& activities)
    {
        return std::accumulate(
                activities.cbegin(), activities.cend(), 0,
                [](int sum, const activity& a){ return sum + a.cost;});
    }

    Activities operator()(std::size_t from, std::size_t to, std::size_t money) const
    {
        // clear cache table
        cacheTable_ = CacheTable();

        return impl(from, to, money);
    }
};
```